# Java OData Service does not accept plus (+) signs in URI

Tags: java, apache, odata, uri, olingo

I am trying to issue the following query using Apache Olingo for OData using Java:

```
URI customersUri = client.newURIBuilder(serviceRoot)
          .appendEntitySetSegment("Customers")
          .filter("CustomerID eq 'Joe'")
          .build();
```

The expected query string that I want is: $filter=CustomerID eq 'Joe'

However, when the library builds the above URI, the actual query string becomes like this:

```
%24filter%3DCustomerID+eq+%27Joe%27
```

Now, the problem is that when I use this query string for my OData Service, it seems that it does not accept the plus (+) signs.  However, when removing the plus signs and use space instead, it works
Any help about this or recommendations please?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-577?jql=project%20%3D%20OLINGO%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20text%20~%20%22query%20string%22) that was fixed in the V4 4.0.0-beta-03 release. Maybe your client library is out of date.

Comment: If I update the client library, then all my code has to change.  Is there a way i can replace the plus sign with a %20 in the URI object?

Comment: @user3423878: Sorry, but I don't know enough about Olingo to answer your question.